# Simple way to test my Identity Provider (Idp) SAML in local

Tags: ruby-on-rails, single-sign-on, saml

I'm trying to implement an Idp in SAML to my Rails application, but I don't find any way to test it. Is there a way to test it locally, for example with a simple Service Provider without lot a configuration required or anything else ?

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find this solution : https://github.com/onelogin/ruby-saml-example. It's a simple example in RoR. You just need to modify the configurations.

Answer (score 1):

I have used SimpleSAMLphp in the past to quickly set up a service provider for testing. It should be easy enough if you can run up a LAMP (Linux) or WAMP (Windows) server.

https://simplesamlphp.org/

Comment: Thx for your answer, I look around this solution but seems too annoying for me, But I find another project simpler to tests in ruby : https://github.com/onelogin/ruby-saml-example

Answer (score 0):

For me the easiest way to test both IdP and SP connections where with the help of the https://www.onelogin.com

Here is one of the tutorials and explanations:[How to use SAML One Login test connectors](https://support.onelogin.com/hc/en-us/articles/202673944-How-to-Use-the-OneLogin-SAML-Test-Connector) `

It works with localhost:3000 and sometimes https://ngrok.com/ helps with the https tunneling